# public bool get set - exception for a page

Tags: c#, asp.net, get, set, boolean-expression

I have the following code on a page:

```
public bool HeaderVisible
    {
        get { return lnkHeader.Visible; }
        set { lnkHeader.Visible = value; }
    }
```

Let's say a specific page I have, Events.aspx, I don't want the element with the ID "lnkHeader" to be visible. How do I do this?

Thank you.

Comment: You mean set accessibility for particular page?

Comment: `lnkHeader.Visible = false;`?  Or, with your property, `HeaderVisible = false;`?  It's not clear what the problem is.

Comment: Yes, in the sidebar where this element is, every page needs a header that says say "Company"

Comment: But, on the one Events.aspx page, I don't need it to say Company.

Comment: David on the page itself it reads:                                                              <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="lnkHeader" CssClass="categoryHeader">About Us</asp:HyperLink>

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I got for the answer.

I wanted to suppress the element with the ID lnkHeader for one page only without affecting the other pages.

This is the public side:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td class="menu" valign="top" runat="server" id="menubar">
            <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="lnkHeader" CssClass="categoryHeader">Company</asp:HyperLink>      
        </td>
        <td class="container" valign="top" runat="server" id="cnbody">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="cphUtilities_Body" runat="server" />
            <div style="clear: both;"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is in the code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Utilities_Master : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    public bool HeaderVisible
    {
        get { return lnkHeader.Visible; }
        set { lnkHeader.Visible = value; }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string url = Request.RawUrl;
        if (url.Contains("Giveaway"))
        {
        menubar.Visible = false; 
    cnbody.Style.Add("width", "950px");
        }
        else
        {
        menubar.Visible = true; 
        }
    }
}
```